# Singular or plural verb after "what"

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, what-clefts

Which sentence is more grammatically correct?

> He is being tried on what **look** like trumped-up charges.
>   He is being tried on what **looks** like trumped-up charges.

Comment: Presumably the first one, given `charges`. I'd imagine you would hear both a lot in common speech, though.

Comment: Both are correct. In the first, *look* refers to the individual charges, while in the second, *looks* refers to the issue of charges as singular. There is no grammatical error; the difference is in semantics.

Answer (score 15):

This is an example of a [free relative clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_relative_clause#Bound_and_free). The relative pronoun can be singular or plural, depending on the context.

In a *bound* relative clause, the relative pronoun has the same grammatical number as its antecedent, but a *free* relative clause has no antecedent. When you're not sure which number to use for a free clause, you can often deduce it by comparing an equivalent independent clause with a demonstrative subject. For example:

> **These look** like trumped-up **charges.**
> **This looks** like trumped-up charges.

Both of these sentences are grammatical, with slightly different meanings. In the first sentence, the subject refers to the charges; in the second, it refers to the situation:

> **This looks** like **[a case of]** trumped-up charges.

Many writers will prefer the first example because the grammatical number obviously agrees throughout, but both are correct. Likewise, both of your examples are correct, although many writers will prefer the first because of the consistent number:

> He is being tried on **what look** like trumped-up **charges.**
> He is being tried on **what looks** like trumped-up charges.

[edit EA; 2023] There are few hits (about 50 each) in Google searches for either "He is being tried on what look like trumped-up charges" *or* "He is being tried on what looks like trumped-up charges". Some of these are other requests for elucidation. The opinions given are in line with the above (both grammatical; proximity (look ... charges) agreement sounds better).

Comment: Hello, Bradd. This has just resurfaced. Have you reasonable references supporting the claims made, that you could kindly add?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What are you looking for support for? The primary claim I made is that this is not a matter of grammatical correctness (i.e. numerical agreement) because the relative pronoun _what_ has no antecedent to agree with, and I linked a source that names and defines the specific grammatical structure. Everything else is subjective stylistic advice, with an explanation for why some folks prefer one over the other, even though neither is more "correct."

Comment: Also, it's been ten years. I have no idea whether or how my source has changed in that time. It may be more or less on point than it was when I wrote this. I stand by what I wrote ten years ago, but I don't see much value in re-researching old work because an algorithm resurfaced it.

Comment: Sorry; for ' Likewise, both of your examples _are correct_, although many writers will prefer the first because of the consistent number:

'He is being tried on _what look like trumped-up charges_' preferred to
'He is being tried on _what looks like trumped-up charges_.'

Comment: I don't understand your question. I'm **not** saying that one is preferable to the other! On the contrary, I explicitly state that both are standard English and differ only in nuance. However, hypercorrection is rampant, and so many people will incorrectly expect that _what_ must agree in number with _charges._ Thus, some writers will prefer that phrasing, if only to keep their editors and audiences from complaining.

Comment: Essentially, I was cautioning _my_ audience that some people may bristle at the latter example even though it's totally fine English that we use in conversation all the time. If I were still an active participant here, I might have something handy about descriptivism vs prescriptivism vs hypercorrection, I guess?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sorry for my verbosity and crankiness. I'm mostly just surprised to get asked for extra work on this answer, because it doesn't seem like a very important answer, and I'm no longer an active user here.

Comment: Sorry to reawaken your contributory thread. It's that this question has been asked anew, and this answer, if given the support (respectable references or supporting data) usually deemed necessary on ELU nowadays, could prevent bloat.

Comment: The trouble with questions like these, where there's actually nothing wrong with either example, is that it's quite difficult to source the _lack_ of a problem. There just aren't many rules for free relative pronouns because they lack an antecedent and don't have an inherent number, so anything goes. I _did_ source that part though, and the rest is opinion, so I still have no idea what else you want here.

Comment: I guess the main problem is that I haven't been a regular here in a long time, so I don't know what the standards are, and so I have little chance of getting it right without putting in a ton of work, including re-learning the culture. I've already spent way too much time on this. Please feel free to adopt the answer yourself.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you!